# Cloning a sheet without the formula(s)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a generated number based by row (Google Form response). However, doing this limits my ability to filter.

I want to create a secondary sheet that updates regularly with the values only (no formulas) then I will gain the function to filter again.

Current sheet called "Ticket Creation" and the New Sheet created/updated called "Active Tickets+".

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  /* Copy current sheet and replaced it >.< */
  var name = "labnol";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ticket Creation');
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getDataRange(), {contentsOnly:true});

  /* Before cloning the sheet, delete any previous copy */
  var old = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old); // or old.setName(new Name);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Utilities.sleep(2000);
  sheet.setName('Active Tickets+');

  /* Make the new sheet active */
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

}
```

Currently this will clone to the same sheet (Ticket Creation) and remove the formulas. I'm just starting to play with scripting.

Answer (score 1):

On the following line you are using the same object as source and destination:

```
sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getDataRange(), {contentsOnly:true});
```

You should use a different range as destination. By the other hand, the order of the statements is wrong because your code clear/create the destination spredsheet after the copyTo statement.

Suggestion, inverse the order and correct the destination of copyTo properly.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options

```
 // The code below will copy only the values of the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange("A:E").copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1"), {contentsOnly:true});
 }
```